# Apply normal map shader

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I noticed in the [SDF specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=material#material_shader) one can add a `<shader>` tag with type `normal_map_tangentspace` to a `<material>` tag. But when I try to load my world file in gazebo 9 (also tried it in 7), the last output I get in the console is `waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...`. It will wait forever.

I also made sure that the `gazebo_model_path` is set up correctly in my package.xml, so the texture file specified in the `<normal_map>` child tag should get found. It works at least for meshes and material scripts. Here is a snippet from my world file:

```
    <model name="model">
        <link name="link">               
            <visual name="visual">
                <geometry>
                    <mesh>
                        <uri>model://mesh.dae</uri>
                    </mesh>
                </geometry>
                <material>
                    <shader type="normal_map_tangentspace">
                        <normal_map>model://materials/textures/Normal.png</normal_map>
                    </shader>
                    <script>
                        <uri>model://materials/scripts</uri>
                        <name>Material</name>
                    </script>
                </material>
            </visual>
        </link>
    </model>
```

Does anyone have experience with this and knows what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,
David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20756/apply-normal-map-shader/) by [D4KU](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6949/d4ku/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-18**:
That console message seems to be coming from ROS and not related to Gazebo's rendering.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-18**:
Also, I'd double-check that you're referring to the correct resource locations, usually you'd have the model name after `model://`

**Comment by [D4KU](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6949/d4ku/) on 2018-10-22**:
I'm pretty confident that the path is correct. I've tested it by using it in the mesh uri as well. The mesh got found after I copied it to the same location as my normal map image. And I double checked its name a 1000 times.
I had the hope that the last output would give someone a hint where gazebo or ROS seem to encounter a problem. Sadly I have no other feedback, since there is no exception being thrown or anything. It just works fine as soon I comment out the  tag in my world file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured it out. I copied 'normal_map_tangentspace' from the [SDF specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=material), but it's a typo. It must say 'normal_map_tangent_space'. That little thing has cost me hours...

---

Originally posted by [D4KU](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6949/d4ku/) with karma: 1 on 2018-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0